# how do i change streaming to Idle?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how would i change below to idle and status watching the server the bot is in?

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Loged in as {bot.user}\n')
  cmds = filter(lambda e: e.endswith(".py"), os.listdir("commands"))
  print(f"Loading Commands")
  for cmd in cmds:
    bot.load_extension(f"commands.{cmd[:-3]}")
    print(f"Loaded {cmd}")
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=f"{len(bot.guilds)} servers  |  {prefix}help", url='https://discord.gg/Mws2mSjde6'))
```

Comment: Is your bot on multiple servers? Do you want to display the number of guilds the bot is in? What exactly does not work? Just providing the code is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Idle(name=f"{len(bot.guilds)} servers  |  {prefix}help"))
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you provide explanation to why this is the solution. Future readers can understand it.